# Alternative to Boom (volume booster)

Tags: sound-volume

I'm disappointed to see that http://www.globaldelight.com/ are discontinuing support for Boom1 and charging users to upgrade to Boom2. In fact their smallprint suggests they intend to charge for Boom3.

As a software developer, it would be against my conscience to charge multiple times for a simple utility that the operating system should have supplied.

So, I am looking for alternatives.  Is there any other way to increase the volume on a MacBook?

PS Is it just my imagination, or has the most recent OSX (El Capitan)  increased the maximum volume level? Since Boost stopped working, I haven't really noticed a problem watching movies.

Comment: The problem that I have found with going past the max is that sounds get more distorted the louder you go.  Is getting external speakers or bluetooth speakers/headset outside the realm of possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try the open source [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

It can boost the audio by upto 200%. The equaliser let's you boost even further.

[image]

[image]

2. You can boost audio in iTunes too. Select the song and press `Cmd+I`

You can boost audio by another 100% and use equaliser too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Soundflower and Loopback both offer functionalities similar to what you had in Boom, and the ability to boost the volume, which is what you requested. https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/